# How can I manipulate files from Spring app

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-integration-sftp

Hi :) My plan is to create and edit some files on ssh server from Spring web app.
Both are on the same server. I read some topics & articles but I'm not sure which one is ok and if it's possible.

1. Spring Integration - SFTP Adapter
2. execute own shell script like from here -> [Execute shell script from spring web application deployed on cloudfoundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338815/execute-shell-script-from-spring-web-application-deployed-on-cloudfoundry)
3. Spring Batch

Thanks for answers and tips :)

Comment: Do you need sftp? Since they are in the same machine you should not need an sftp connection

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your use case? what is the trigger of your job of creating/editing the files? What kind of processing are you going to do?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Via web interface I add new account and create pair of keys for this account. That keys I'd like to store in database and as a file in folder at the same virtual machine. Also I'd like to add a public key to authorized keys file on this machine. That things I want to achive after add new account.